# Newform of a cuspidal Automorphic Representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I was going through these notes https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ty245/2008_AGR_Fall/2008_agr_week1.pdf . There, Theorem 9.2 states that: If $\pi ^{\infty}$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb A^{\infty})$ (on $V$), then there exists $N \in \mathbb Z _{>0}$ with $V^{U_1(N)} \ne 0$ and for minimal such $N$, we have $\dim_{\mathbb C}V^{U_1(N)} = 1$. The cusp form $\varphi \in \mathcal A_k( U_1(N))$ generating (unique upto scalar) $V^{U_1(N)}$ is *defined* to be a "newform".

Later it is shown that this $\varphi$ gives a classicial cusp form w.r.t. $\Gamma_1(N)$. My question is:

**Quetion:** Does it follow that $\varphi$ is a newform according to the classical definition (i.e., the one involving Petersson inner product)?

I understand that $\varphi$ is a Hecke eigenform w.r.t. $T_n$ and $<n>$ for $n>0$. So it follows that $\varphi$ is either a newform or an old form. If it is an old form one can associate a newform $f$ to it with some conductor $M \mid N$. I was trying to show that $f \in V$, which, then by minimality of $N$ would answer the question.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $\varphi$ being a classical newform?  Atkin-Lehner defined classical newforms for $\Gamma_0(N)$, not for $\Gamma_1(N)$.

Comment: I'm using the notion from Diamond Shurman.

Comment: Ah, I thought by $\Gamma_1$ you meant unipotent mod $N$, but the notes you refer to work with another definition of $\Gamma_1$.  So there's no problem.

Comment: The link to the notes is unavailable now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the classical version of this adelic newform is the newform in the sense of Atkin-Lehner, and vice versa. See Casselman: On some results of Atkin and Lehner (Math. Ann. 201 (1973), 301-314), especially Theorem 4 there. Another important reference is Miyake: On automorphic forms on GL_2, and  Hecke operators (Ann. of Math. 94 (1971), 174-189.). See also Sections 5.3-5.4 in Goldfeld-Hundley: Automorphic Representations and L-Functions for the General Linear Group, Volume 1.

**Added.** To your last paragraph: the adelization of $f$ lies in $V$, because it has the same Hecke eigenvalues as $\varphi$. The multiplicity one theorem says (or implies) that adelic (almost) Hecke cusp forms with the same Hecke eigenvalues (outside any finite set of places) generate the same cuspidal representation.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely take a detailed look at the sources you cited. Meanwhile, I would like to ask if it is possible to prove it the way I was trying to, i.e., does there exist a $g \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb A^{\infty})$ such that $g \cdot \varphi = f?$ (In above notations)

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal: Yes, this is a consequence of the multiplicity one theorem (which is ultimately an analytic result), see my added section. The multiplicity one result is very important: it is present in Casselman's paper (Theorem 2) and in Miyake's paper (Corollary to Theorem A) as well. It says that Hecke eigenvalues (or Hecke eigenvalues outside any finite set of places) identifies the cuspidal representation (and hence its 1-dimensional newspace as well).

Comment: Does one really need to use the multiplicity one theorem here? Can't one find the relevant $g \in GL_2(\mathbb A^{\infty})$ explicitly, as $\begin{pmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ or something like that?

Comment: @WillSawin: You are right, if we know for classical forms that $f(z)=g(dz)$ with $g$ a newform, then a similar relation holds for their adelic versions: $\phi(g)=\psi\left(g\left(\begin{smallmatrix}d^{-1}&\\&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right)$ if I recall correctly.

Comment: In this case don't we have something like $\varphi(z) = \sum_{nM \mid N}c_nf(nz)$ (where $\varphi$ is the old form and $f$ is the associated newform with conductor $M$)? Does the same thing work if we are trying to write $f$ as some $g \cdot \varphi$? The formula in this case doesn't look absolutely clear to me.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal: Right. Let $\tilde\varphi$ (resp. $\tilde f_M$) be the adelization of $\varphi$ (resp. $f_M=f$). Then $\tilde\phi(g)=\sum_{\substack{M\mid N\\M<N}}\sum_{n\mid\frac{N}{M}} \tilde f_M\left(g\left(\begin{smallmatrix}n^{-1}&\\&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right)$. The inner sum is orthogonal to $\pi$, because it lies in a cuspidal representation of conductor $M\neq N$ (here I use multiplicity one). Hence the whole sum is orthogonal to $\pi$, hence also to $\tilde\phi$ (i.e. to itself), which is a contradiction.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal: A coefficient $c_{n,M}$ (which is your $c_n$) should be included in my inner sum (in the previous comment). I am lazy to retype.

Comment: I believe Casselman only works with the $\Gamma_0$ type subgroups, not $\Gamma_1$.  I think one needs to be careful going from newforms of a $\Gamma_0$ level to a $\Gamma_1$ level as potentially the level can drop.  Is this addressed in any of the references you give?

Comment: @Kimball: The references I mentioned do not address $\Gamma_1$ vs. $\Gamma_0$, but I think the two types of conductors are the same. Namely, if $U_1(N)$ fixes $\phi$ with $N$ minimal for the representation $\pi$ containing $\phi$, then $U_0(N)$ has to act on $\phi$ by "a character mod $N$" which is uniquely determined by the central character of $\pi$, and by definition this means that $\pi$ has conductor $N$ and $\phi$ is a newform for $\pi$ in the usual sense (which directly translates to Atkin-Lehner sense in the classical theory). And vice versa.

Comment: Ah, there are two possible ways to define $\Gamma_1$, and my default interpretation is unipotent mod $N$, in which case I think the levels can be different.  But the OP seems to be talking about the $\Gamma_1$ that is closer to $\Gamma_0$, so I agree the conductors are the same in this situation.

Comment: @Kimball: Yes. I used the convention in the lecture notes linked by the OP (see Example 5.9 there).